# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

So im following this tutorial and im struggling with the following step. Redux was introduced and it not working. I googled the error that I found in the developer Tool and I still couldn't fix the error by trying many proposed solutions. The error is in HomeScreen in line 25 (products.map) My code:

HomeScreen.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import { useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {listProducts} from '../actions/productActions'


function HomeScreen() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
    const {error, loading, products} = productList

    useEffect(() =>{
        dispatch(listProducts())
    },[dispatch])
    
  return (
    
        <div>
            <h1>Latest Products</h1>
            {loading ? <h2>Loading..</h2>
                : error ? <h3>{error}</h3>
                :
                <Row>
                {products.map(product => (
                    <Col key={product._id} sm={8} md={6} lg={4} xl={2}>
                        <Product product={product} />
                    </Col>
                ))}
                </Row>
            }
            
        </div>
    
  )
}
```

store.js:

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import {productListReducer} from './reducers/productReducers'


const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
})
const initialState = {}
const middleware = [thunk]
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, 
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```

productActions.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL} from '../constants/productConstants'

export const listProducts = () =>  async(dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST})

        const {data} =  await axios.get('/api/products/')

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message, 
        })
    }
}
```

productReducers.js

```
import {
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL
} from '../constants/productConstants'


export const productListReducer = (state={products:[]},action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return {loading:true, product:[]}

        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {loading:false, product:action.payload}

        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return {loading:false, error: action.payload}
        
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error tell you?

Comment: When does the `productList` array become undefined? I see two possibilities: (1) `action.payload` is undefined in the `PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS` reducer case, or (2) there's an error and the `PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL` action is dispatched which removes the `products` array.

Comment: try: `products?.map(product => (`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consistently name the state. The state is initially named `products`, but all the case reducers replace it with `product`. Don't forget to also always shallow copy the previous state object into the next state object.

```
export const productListReducer = (state={ products: [] }, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        products: [],
      };

    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload,
        error: null,
      };

    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```